# Can you get a index number from arraylist input?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Lets say you have 2 names in a ArrayList

1. Jonh Smith
2. Jane Doe

A user enters the name "Jane Doe" and the system prints out 1 (its position in the array?)

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking.  you might want to edit your question to make it clear what the problem is and what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method. It returns a zero-based index, so you would need to add one to the result:

```
List<String> names = ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Jonh Smith");
names.add("Jane Doe");
...
int position = names.indexOf("Jane Doe") + 1;
System.out.println(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use `int index = yourArrayList.indexOf("Jane Doe")` to find its position.

More info: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

You should review the [IndexOf method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

you should give a little more effort to at least try to find it our yourself.
Don't expect people to spoon feed you with code.

That said, here's the page you'll need for your research and the function you're looking for is indexOf() .

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, then I think you want something using [ArrayList#indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29), that is like -

```
// and str is a String from your user.
String str = "Jane Doe";
String[] names = { "Jonh Smith", "Jane Doe" };
List<String> al = Arrays.asList(names);
System.out.println(al.indexOf(str));
```